# On click set focus on textarea angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

```
<div class="posts">    
   <div class="post">
      <div>post content</div>
    <a class="comment">Comment</a>

    <textarea [(ngModel)]= "model.text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
       <div>post content</div>
    <a class="comment">Comment</a>

    <textarea [(ngModel)]= "model.text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I want to set focus on textarea on 'a' click. Can anyone please help me. I'm using angular 5

Comment: just use a querySelector or ViewChild and call .focus() on the resulting element.

Comment: Use `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` to achieve this. Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you may go for loop the `<div class="post">`,

```
<div class="posts">    
  <div class="post">
    <div>post content</div>
    // Pass index here, if you want to achieve dynamically
    <a class="comment" (click)="doSomething(0)">Comment</a>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]= "model.text" class="comment-text" #txtArea name="text"> 
    </textarea>
  </div>   
  <div class="post">
    <div>post content</div>
    <a class="comment" (click)="doSomething(1)">Comment</a>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]= "model.text" class="comment-text" #txtArea name="text"> 
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in your ts file add the following imports,

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Read elements using `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` like this,

```
@ViewChildren("txtArea") textAreas:QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Finally your `doSomething` event handler like this,

```
doSomething(index: number) {
  this.textAreas.find((item, idx) => {
    return idx === index;
  }).nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**Update**

The above code will work with an array of `posts`. So we don't need to hard-code the id like #txtArea1, #txtArea2 etc.
Please check here the [DEMO_1](https://angular-m4ugrk.stackblitz.io)
If you are iterating `<div class="post">` like,
`<div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts; index as i">` 
 You can pass the `index`(here `i`) to get corresponding `TextArea` reference from `QueryList` like below,

```
<a class="comment" (click)="textAreas.toArray()[i].nativeElement.focus()">Comment</a>
```

Check the complete code here [DEMO_2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4ugrk)

Answer (score 11):

You can set focus directly from your markup in HTML file if you use template variables. You can reference it in `(click)` method. This way, no need to access DOM thru the code, it stays in HTML file, easier for debugging:

**HTML**

```
...
<textarea #textarea1 [(ngModel)]="text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
<button (click)="textarea1.focus()">SetFocus on the first textarea</button>
...
<textarea #textarea2 [(ngModel)]="text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
<button (click)="textarea2.focus()">SetFocus on the second textarea</button>
...
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9stnu)**

Comment: Thanks Vega, his was my case. And I like the idea of keeping it in HTML. Best!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the @ViewChild decorator. Documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild.

You need to assign a name to your input element and wire up a click event.

```
<textarea #inputToFocus />
 <a (click)="focusInput()">Click</button>
```

In your component, use @ViewChild to search for the element, then implement the click handler to perform whatyou need.

```
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("inputToFocus") inputElement: ElementRef;

  focusInput() {
    this.inputElement.nativeElement.focus()
  }
```

NOTE:The `inputElement` variable will be first available, when `ngAfterViewInit` event fires.

UPDATE DUE TO UPDATED QUESTION: To handle multiple elements you would need to use @ViewChildren Documentation:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

In the code example you gave above I would make the redundant code into its own component to encapsulate the repeated functionality.

Comment: Thanks. If I have multiple textarea and 'a' then how can I achive this.